# Will multithreading improve performance significantly if I have a fixed amount of calculations that are independet from each other?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, sdl

I am programming a raycasting game engine.
Each ray can be calculated without knowing anything about the other rays (I'm only calculating distances).
Since there is no waiting time between calculations, I wonder whether it's worth the effort to make the ray calculations multithreaded or not.
Is it likely that there will be a performance boost?

Comment: I would be nice to have a description about the calculations to be made for a ray. Furthermore you should provide information how many rays you need to calculate per frame/event? In general its impossible to say if multithreading would provide a performance benefit. It depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: There are 320 rays every frame. Would 320 threads be a good or a bad idea?

Comment: Do you have 320 cores? Probably not. But if you're moving to GPGPU solutions that becomes viable. (Well, they're not exactly C++ threads there, but you can calculate 320 rays in parallel there)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mostly likely multi-threading will improve performance if done correctly. The way you've stated your problem, it is a perfect candidate for multi-threading since the computations are independent, reducing the need for coordination between threads to a minimum.

Some reasons you *still* might not get a speed up, or may not get the full speed up you expect could include:

1) The bottleneck may not be on-die CPU execution resources (e.g., ALU-bound operations), but rather something shared like memory or shared LLC bandwidth.

For example, on some architectures, a single thread may be able to saturate memory bandwidth, so adding more cores may not help. A more common case is that a single core can saturate some fraction, 1/N < 1 of main memory bandwidth, and this value is larger than 1/C where C is the core count. For instance, on a 4 core box, one core may be able to consume 50% of the bandwidth. Then, for a memory-bound computation, you'll get good scaling to 2 cores (using 100% of bandwidth), but little to none above that.

Other resources which are shared among cores include disk and network IO, GPU, snoop bandwidth, etc. If you have a hyper-threaded platform, this list increases to include all levels of cache and ALU resources for logical cores sharing the same physical core.

2) Contention "in practice" between operations which are "theoretically" independent.

You mention that your operations are independent. Typically this means that they are *logically* independent - they don't share any data (other than perhaps immutable input) and they can write to separate output areas. That doesn't exclude the possibility, however, than any given implementation actually has some hidden sharing going on.

One classic example is false-sharing - where independent variables fall in the same cache line, so logically independent writes to different variables from different threads end up thrashing the cache line between cores.

Another example, frequently encountered in practice, is contention via library - if your routines use malloc heavily, you may find that all the threads spend most of their time waiting on a lock inside the allocator as malloc is shared resource. This can be remedied by reducing reliance on malloc (perhaps via fewer, larger mallocs) or with a good concurrent malloc such as hoard or tcmalloc.

3) Implementation of the distribution and collection of the computation across threads may overwhelm the advantage you get from multiple threads. For example, if you spin up a new thread for every individual ray, the thread creation overhead would dominate your runtime and you would likely see a negative benefit. Even if you use a thread-pool of persistent threads, choosing a "work unit" that is too fine grained will impose a lot of coordination overhead which may eliminate your benefits.

Similarly, if you have to copy the input data to and from the worker threads, you may not see the scaling you expect. Where possible, use pass-by-reference for read-only data.

4) You don't have more than 1 core, or you do have more than 1 core but they are already occupied running other threads or processes. In these cases, the effort to coordinate multiple threads is pure overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Probably yes, multithreading (e.g. with [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)) could improve performance; but you surely want to benchmark (and you might be disappointed if your program is memory bound, not CPU bound). And you could also consider [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) (to run some *regular* numeric computations on the GPGPU) and [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) (to explicitly ask the compiler, thru pragmas, to parallelize some of your code).
Maybe [Open-MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) might be considered to run on several *communicating* processes. And if you are brave (or crazy) you could mix several approaches.

In reality, it depends upon the algorithm and the system (both hardware and operating system), and you should benchmark (e.g. some micro-prototype related to your needs).

If on some particular system the bottleneck is the memory bandwidth (not the CPU), multi-threading or multi-processing won't help much (and probably could *degrade* performance).
Also, the cost of synchronization may vary widely (e.g. locking a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex) can be very fast on some systems and 50x slower on others).

Answer (score 2):

In general, *it depends*.  Given that the calculations are independent, it sounds like this is a good candidate for potential performance improvements due to threading.  Ray calculations typically can benefit from this.

However, there are many other factors, such as memory access requirements, as well as the underlying system on which this runs, which will have a tremendous impact on this.  It's often possible to have multithreaded versions run slower than single threaded versions if not written correctly, so profiling is the only way to answer this definitively.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely. Independent calculations are a perfect candidate for parallelization. In the case of raycasting, there is so many of them that they would spread nicely across as many parallel threads as the hardware permits.

An unexpected bottleneck for calculations that would otherwise have perfect data-independence can be concurrent writes to nearby locations (*false sharing* of cache lines).